# Delete Firebase document on bootstrap modal confirmation button

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, bootstrap-4, google-cloud-firestore

I need some advise on how to go about editing user by document ID from the firebase database.

After user clicks the icon it will bring up bootstrap modal and I need to update user information.

On edit button click, it takes you to the editUser Function passing the user information to the function to be used. This function fires up a bootstrap modal to make the changes and then it should save the information back to the database.

It does not applies the changes when user has updates information.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row bg-dark">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p class="text-center text-light display-4 pt-2" style="font-size: 25px">CRUD Application Using Vue.js</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-lg-6 ">
            <h3 class="text-info mt-0 float-left">Registered Users</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <button class="btn btn-info float-right" @click="showAddModal=true">
              <i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add New User
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="bg-info">
        <div v-if="errorMsg" class="alert alert-danger">Error Message</div>
        <div v-if="successMsg" class="alert alert-success">Success Message</div>

        <!--Display Records-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <thead>
              <tr class="text-center bg-info text-light">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr v-for="(user, idx) in users" :key="idx" class="text-center">
                <td>{{ idx + 1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
                <td><a class="text-success" href="#" @click="editUser(user)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                <td><a class="text-danger" href="#" @click="showDeleteModal=true"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Add New User Model-->
      <div v-if="showAddModal" id="add" class="overlay">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Add New User</h5>
              <button class="close" type="button" @click="showAddModal=false">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body p-4">
              <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input v-model="user.name" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="name" placeholder="Name"
                         type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input v-model="user.email" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="email" placeholder="Email"
                         type="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input v-model="user.phone" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"
                         type="tel">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg"
                          @click="showAddModal=false; saveNewUser(); successMsg=true">Add User
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Edit User Model-->
      <div v-if="showEditModal" id="edit" class="overlay" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Update User</h5>
              <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" @click="showEditModal=false">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body p-4">
              <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input v-model="user.name" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="name" placeholder="Name"
                         type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input v-model="user.email" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="email" placeholder="Email"
                         type="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input v-model="user.phone" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"
                         type="tel">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg" @click="showAddModal=false; updateUser()">Update User
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Delete User Model-->
      <div v-if="showDeleteModal" id="delete" class="overlay">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Delete User</h5>
              <button class="close" type="button" @click="showDeleteModal=false">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body p-4">
              <h4 class="text-danger">Are you sure you want to delete this user?</h4>
              <h5>You are Deleting 'Kevin'</h5>
              <hr>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" @click="showDeleteModal=false">Yes</button>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" @click="showDeleteModal=false">no</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import {db} from './firebase'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      errorMsg: false,
      successMsg: false,
      showAddModal: false,
      showEditModal: false,
      showDeleteModal: false,
      users: [],
      currentUser: null,
      user: {
        userID: null,
        name: null,
        email: null,
        phone: null
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {

    // Displays all users stores in firebase
    displayAllUsers() {
      db.collection("patients").get().then((querySnapshot) => {

        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

          this.users.push(doc.data());
        });

      });
    },

    // Creates New User with an auto generated Document
    saveNewUser() {
      db.collection("patients").add(this.user)
          .then((docRef) => {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            this.displayAllUsers();
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
          });
    },

    // Edit User
    editUser(user) {
      this.showEditModal = true;
      this.user = user.data();
      this.currentUser = user.id;
    },

    // Update User
    updateUser() {

      db.collection("patients").doc(this.currentUser).update(this.user)
          .then(function () {
            console.log("Document successfully updated!");
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // The document probably doesn't exist.
            console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
          });
    },

    // Delete User
    deleteUser(doc) {
      db.collection("patients").doc(doc).delete().then(function () {
        console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
      });
    },

    // Reset the data from the input field to null
    reset() {
      // Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.apply((this)));
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.displayAllUsers();
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now?  Please edit the question to explain the problem in more detail, and what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I have edited the question with more details.

Comment: Are there any errors? Other debugging information?  We can't see what's going on here - please illustrate with logs and such.

Comment: Additionally to the questions above please add as well mentioned but not shown `editUser` function

Comment: Code was not updated, I have uploaded the error message when trying the edit feature.

Comment: Maybe you should log the user to see what exactly object used as argument and if such object have `data` method?